# Which of Usopp's lies have not come true?

Tags: one-piece

A running gag in One Piece is that Usopp's lies eventually turn out to be true (with some minor modifications such as his age). For instance, he discovered giant goldfish, pirates came (though they don't find out), and the existence of an island of dwarves. I fully expect every significant lie he says from the beginning of the story to come true in some (likely absurd) way at some point in the story.

I want to know the lies which are yet to come true. Currently, I am only aware that he lied about a medicine that can cure any disease. His claims to be captain could potentially count, but he has been acknowledged by the title "Captain Usopp".

What other lies are left that have not yet come true?

Comment: None, you got that all right. There's a Korean website that I just checked for you, and the person who has studied One Piece the whole time said that those are the ones that are yet to come. --- Source: [Daum Cafe BBS](https://cluster1.cafe.daum.net/_c21_/bbs_search_read?grpid=aSh8&fldid=70Pu&datanum=572&openArticle=true&docid=aSh870Pu57220130325004522) (Korean, post already deleted)

Comment: Potential other lies:  Ussop is related to Norland, the existance of sniper island, and he can wield a 5Ton Hammer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm using [the YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uXx3FoHnVQ) (note: already taken down) OP provided in one of the comments to answer this question.

Basically, the lies that haven't come true according to this video are:

- (Conqueror's) Haki
- Having 8000 followers
- Medicine that cures all diseases
- Brave warrior of the sea
- King Usopp from hell
- Beating ten giant shadows
- Assisting in bringing down a bombman
- Descendant of Noland
- Being born on Sniper Island

Personally, I believe three of them have been verified in recent chapters though.

> - Haki could be considered as truth as he indeed unlocked (Observation) Haki and he will most likely not discover Conqueror's Haki.
>  - Law's DF could be considered the medicine that cures all diseases as he could cure fatal diseases such as lead poisoning and could even cure the terminal illness called death.
>  - Assisting in bringing down a bombman is probably referring to the fact that he sniped Sugar the second time, bringing down the giant toys that were aiding.

---

For completeness, here are the lies that have been confirmed according to the same video:

- Pirates came to Syrup village (Black Cat Pirates)
- Saved a whale from North Blue (Laboon)
- Fought a huge goldfish with poop as large as islands (The goldfish at Little Garden killed by Brogy and Dorry. The same goldfish had pooped the island called Nanimonai)
- "Honestly, I know I'm a man among men, but you can't fall in love with me, girl. Not my fault if you get burned." (Basically what Sanji told the Okama)
- A big condor, flying through the skies (The big condors Chopper met during the time-skip. Usopp rode one during the reunion)
- Abominable snowman (Rock and Scotch, the Yeti Cool brothers)
- A beautiful female swordmaster who brought a lot of meat (Rebecca buying Luffy three bentos at the Colosseum)
- A huge mole inside the mansion (Miss Merry Christmas from Baroque Works)
- During the Syrup Village arc, they pretend to chase "Cerberus", while chasing a regular dog (Usopp met a real Cerberus at Thriller Bark)
- They also pretend to capture a dragon (The Straw Hat Pirates actually capture (eat) a dragon on Punk Hazard)
- Country of dwarves (Tontatta country)
- Legendary hero Usoland (God Usopp)

Comment: Doesn't "God Usopp" command ~8000 followers to destroy the factory behind him? (perhaps if you include the Tontattas in the count as well)

Comment: @user2813274 Well they all turned on him after he got his 500 mio bounty though. So during that one chapter it could be considered true, but I left it out cos I believr thr Straw Hat divisions are about to be formed after this arc ends and then he will truly have many loyal followers.

Comment: This isn't relevant anymore but Ussop makes a "snow queen" (beautiful snow woman) all they way back in Whiskey Peak which comes true in Punk Hazard.

Comment: Can we count born on Sniper Island as his "rebirth" from being with Heracle for the 2 years that he was there for the time being?

Comment: Usopp will soon command 8,000 followers considering that after Dreadrossa Arc they got 5,000+ new allies under their wing and as the story continues more will be added.

Comment: He actually has Haki (it's shown in the Dressrosa arc).

Comment: Assisting in bringing down a bombman. That was Mr. 6 or 5, I believe. He clearly destroyed them on Little Garden.

Comment: Beating ten giant shadows.

This can count as beating some of the angels from Skypia since their shadows were 'giant shadows'. So, by beating them up in Skypia, he beat the shadows.

Comment: There is one more lie. Ussop said "First, for the giant cat, I used a cattail plant" back in episode 9, 22:12. This kinda happened later on in ep 765, where he stands beside Robin who uses a cattail plant to calm Nekomamushi.

Comment: What about the bombman from Crocodile Crew?

Comment: This lie has turned to truth - "Assisting in bringing down a bombman." On Little Garden, when Zoro, Nami, and Vivi were stuck in the candle, he fought against Mr.5 and Miss Valentine (Mr.5 is a bombman, he said so himself on Whisky Peak) and won by freeing Zoro so he could beat Mr.5.

Answer (score 1):

I remember one during the Thriller Bark arc. Where he tries to wake Luffy, Zoro and Sanji up by yelling that there is a beautiful lady swordsman with a ton of meat.

I think that one would be good to see if it comes true.

Comment: I'm not sure about this one - after all, in Dressrosa, Rebecca feeds Luffy... (and I'm anticipating a feast in a few more episodes)

Comment: I don't really know what a significant lie is either but I think this might count as one as long as it was in the manga.  Thank you!  Now it could easily come true with Tashigi or Rebecca but i've not seen them with meat yet in the anime (I don't know what Rebecca fed Luffy).

Comment: The bento rebecca bought Luffy most likely contained meat. Luffy wouldn't be scuffing down free samples of vegetables.